# IDOC file generation in ecommerce system

Tags: idoc, sap-r3

I want to generate an IDOC file to make shop orders availabe to the R/3 SAP System. My question is concerning **BELNR** in **E2EDK01**. As we dont have the possibility to use Webservices and BAPI, we only make the data available via files.

Actual questions are:

Do i yet need a **[BELNR]** in the IDOC file?
If yes, where to get this **[BELNR]** from?

Answer (score 1):

E2EDK01-BELNR is the order number of the ordering party, normally it is not needed, but useful.

Example:
The customer sends an order and is unsure if the order received you. So he sends the order again. Now you have two similar orders. You can't know, if there are two similar orders or if you have two idocs for the same order.

If E2EDK01-BELNR is filled with the order number of the customer system, you can decide how to proceed (e.g. ignore the 2nd idoc).

If I understand your question correct, you create the order out of your shop system. You could offer an (optional) field like 'Your order number' and use this. If the same order number (per customer) is used again you can make a warning ("*Order X is already ordered*").

If you don't want this field you could use the session id to identify double postings.